# How to pass multiselected values from checkbox and pass it to front end application in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

```
<html>
    <script>
    function monthFilter(month) {

                var sheet = viz.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet();
                if (month === "") {
                    sheet.clearFilterAsync("Month");
                } else {
                    sheet.applyFilterAsync("Month", month, tableau.FilterUpdateType.REPLACE);
                }
                }
    </script>


      $('#Dyanmic').treeview({
                        data: jsonCalendarTreeStructure,
                        showCheckbox: true,
                        multiSelect: true,


                    });

                    $('#Dyanmic').on('nodeChecked', function (event, data) {


                        //console.log(data);
                        //console.log(data);
                        if (data.type=="Y")
                            yearFilter(data.text);
                        else if (data.type=="Q")
                            quarterFilter(data.text);
                            else if (data.type=="M")
                            monthFilter(data.text);


                        //22
                        // Selected



                        //23
                    });
                     $('#Dyanmic').on('nodeUnchecked', function (event, data) {

                        if (data.type=="Y")
                            yearFilter("");
                        else if (data.type=="Q")
                            quarterFilter("");
                            else if (data.type=="M")
                            monthFilter("");
    });
    </html>
```

Above i have included only the code where i am facing problem. My objective is to create a Checkbox Filter and pass it to the UI. 
**Issue** is, When i select the filter only one value(Recent Selected value) is getting passed, Example When i select month value 17-01, i able to see the data for 17-01, when i additionally select 17-02, now only the value 17-02 gets passed and 17-01 is replaced.
**Requirement** is, i need to pass multi values like 17-01,17-02 on multi select in the checkbox Can anyone help me to solve my problem.

**Note** I am getting filter value from JSON, below is a sample code

```
[

                {
                    text: "Years",

                    nodes: [
            {
                text: "2017",
                type: "Y",
                nodes: [
                {
                    text: "17-Q1",
                    type: "Q",
                },
                                     {
                                         text: "17-01",
                                         type: "M",
                                     },
                                {
                                    text: "17-02",
                                },
                                {
                                    text: "17-03",
                                }
                ]

            }
                    ]
                    }
                ];
```

Comment: I think you need to store checked values into an array, on each event push/pop to/from that array

Comment: Can you please share a sample code and let me know where to change it, Thanks !!